# Implementing counting sort with custom objects

Tags: swift, algorithm

I want to implement a counting sort but want to implement this with custom objects. This is in Swift, but the implementation details are not too important.

I want to sort an object which basically just holds an Integer (key) and a character.

```
class ToSort : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return String(num)
    }
    var num : Int
    var val : Character
    init(_ num: Int, _ val : Character)  {
        self.num = num
        self.val = val
    }
}
```

Now usually the frequencies of integers are stored (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/). I want to store my objects - I'm not sure how to do this. I've spent some time looking for implementations (with custom objects - I've got a link just above here for the standard implementation), cannot find one and cannot work out how I should implement this...

I think I can do this by implementing a dictionary (hashmap), but if I'm doing that is the advantage of using a counting sort lost?

Comment: you sort base on the num ?

Comment: Yes, sort based on the num.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error - One solution is a dictionary, but I do not know if this is a regular solution for this problem. It is perfectly usual to use counting sort for custom objects, but I do not have access to a solution in any language, and can only leverage my own using dictionaries, or 2D arrays.

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns: I probably misunderstood. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this algorithm i implemented it to use custom object might give you an idea of how its done,

```
struct Foo {
    var number: Int
    var name: String
}

enum CountingSortError: Error {
    case arrayEmpty
}

func countingSort(array: [Foo]) throws -> [Foo] {
    guard array.count > 0 else {
        throw CountingSortError.arrayEmpty
    }

    // Step 1
    // Create an array to store the count of each element
    let maxElement = array.max{ a, b in a.number < b.number } ?? Foo(number: 0, name: "Zero")
    var countArray = [Int](repeating: 0, count: Int(maxElement.number + 1))
    for element in array {
        countArray[element.number] += 1
    }

    // Step 2
    // Set each value to be the sum of the previous two values
    for index in 1 ..< countArray.count {
        let sum = countArray[index] + countArray[index - 1]
        countArray[index] = sum
    }

    print(countArray)
    // Step 3
    // Place the element in the final array as per the number of elements before it
    let count = array.count
    var sortedArray = [Foo](repeating: Foo(number: 0, name: ""), count: count)
     sortedArray = array.sorted(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    countArray[a.number] -= 1
    return a.number < b.number
    })
    return sortedArray
}
```

**Usage** :

```
print(try countingSort(array: [Foo(number: 10, name: ""), Foo(number: 9, name: ""), Foo(number: 8, name: ""), Foo(number: 7, name: ""), Foo(number: 1, name: ""), Foo(number: 2, name: ""), Foo(number: 7, name: ""), Foo(number: 3, name: "")]).flatMap {$0.number})
```

**Output**

```
  count [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  sorted [1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The base algorithm [code](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Counting%20Sort/CountingSort.playground/Contents.swift)

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, as it is no longer stable - try countingSort(array: [Foo(number: 3, name: "a"), Foo(number: 1,name: "0"), Foo(number: 2,name: "0"), Foo(number: 3,name: "c")]) returns [{number 1, name "0"}, {number 2, name "0"}, {number 3, name "c"}, {number 3, name "a"}]

Comment: based on numbers its `[1, 2, 3, 3]` isn't that right ?  and count of `count [0, 1, 2, 4]`

Comment: Counting sort should be stable, so we preserve the order of elements with the same key. In the example above, the order is not preserved of the two elements with number 3. Reference: https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/counting-sort

Comment: It can work with a modification to reverse the search of the input array, but this seems a quite non-standard way of going about things don't you think?

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns check updated answer please i change the final sort function

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns i used the `.sort()`  function provided from swift so i think this should stable instead of the for loop

Comment: LOL. I've marked it as accepted, but if you're using .sort for the array you might as well just, well, .sort the array of objects initially rather than using a counting sort (using a sort there really makes no sense at all). But thanks anyway.